# How do I create a component that gives VBA access to my own running Application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, com

I am sorry but I simply don't know the terminology here.  I am not looking for a complete solution just help on what Technologies to search for or a tutorial if possible.

I have a .NET application and I want to give VBA access to the currently running instance of my application.  In other words I want to create similar access to my application as Microsoft does to a running instance of Office Word or Excel.

I can create a COM visible .dll which VBA can use, but now I want it to use my currently running application.

Comment: Because VBA is not going to be what this code is going to be written in. It is going to be written in .NET and my preference is VB.NET.  I just want it COM visible so that VBA can use it.

Comment: i think your question terminology is how to develop an IDE (like vba has vbe) to my application. searched on google, found nothing and upvoted for that question. i suggest you add more tags (vb.net tag [sadly] is not having much views)

Comment: What tags would you suggest?  I am not sure I want to create an IDE.  I think what I want is to register a running instance of my Application with the ROT so that I can "get an active object" I think this is called moniker.

Comment: seems to be more like moniker, i suggest to add c#, vba tags.

Comment: Not enough time to write a full answer, but you want inter-process communications.  You could do this using network sockets and such, but COM's the easier approach.  Note that in Visual Studio 2015 (the "Community" version is free), once you create a project (probably VB.NET in your case), you can go to "Project" in the tool bar, then select Properties at the bottom.  Then in the first tab, "Application", there's a button for "Assembly Information".  There's a check box for "Make assembly COM-Visible".

Comment: UWP offers a new model for inter-process communications if you're wiling to use just Windows 10+, but since it's a recent development there's less documentation and fewer intro tutorials on that topic, which may make it a difficult approach if you're doing this for the first time.

Comment: Related:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/612604/Best-Practice-in-Writing-a-COM-Visible-Assembly-Cs

Comment: Thanks Chemical. Best Practice in Writing a COM-Visible Assembly seems to create an assembly which is COM visible but this does not access a running instance of my application. I also have already written the application so a UWP is not now possible.

Comment: @darbid Ohhh gotcha.  I've had that same problem before, but I didn't figure out how to access the already-running app through COM; I'm not even sure if that's possible, as it could be a huge security hole if COM any application could connect to any COM object.  Instead, I wrote a socket-based communication protocol.  I'd have a server process run locally; whenever the application started, it'd sign into the local server.  Then you could write a .NET client that's COM accessible.  Then, in VBA, you can use COM to create a new client that connects to the server, and through it to your app.

Comment: @darbid Though, looking at Aurora's recent answer, I suspect that my approach was re-inveting the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for an Out-of-Process COM server, which runs in a separate process. This allows clients to attach to an already running instance of your application. For an example, check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977996) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Aurora - I understand the terminology or search words "Out-of-Process Com Server" now. but I am still unsure about the attaching to a running instance. What is this technically called?

Comment: I am not sure about the technical term, however it follows this pattern: you'll build a new Out-of-Process COM server and embed your application logic into it. After you've performed the registration steps, you can start the server by running the application exe and creating a new instance. VBA clients can then attach to this instance by calling `GetObject()` with the appropriate class name.

Comment: Thanks Aurora.  I wanted to give you the answer, but will add something as well.

Answer (score 1):

I did ask for just the terminology for what I wanted, but I have found very little information on this in VB.NET.

The example [given above by Aurora from MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977996http://) is an example of an Out-OF-Process COM server where you can only call CreateObject in for example VBA.  You cannot call getobject as this example does not add the necessary infomation to the Running Object Table (ROT).

This means you cannot use this example if you want to access an already running application.

To fix this you need to call [RegisterActiveObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221551(v=vs.85).aspx) on an instance of VBSimpleObject to add your class to the ROT.  I could not find a reliable WinAPI signature of this in VB.NET so here are the register and revoke signatures

```
 <DllImport("oleaut32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function RegisterActiveObject(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)> ByVal pUnk As Object, _
                                            ByRef rclsid As Guid, ByVal dwFlags As IntPtr, _
                                            <Out()> ByRef lpdwRegister As UInt32) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("oleaut32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function RevokeActiveObject(ByVal dwRegister As UInt32, ByVal reserved As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

These work so I hope they are right.

There are probably things now to do with reference counting and when to call the revoke, but I can now call GetObject.

Comment: Yes, I missed that point in my comment. As you noted correctly, the object needs to be registered in the ROT before clients can attach to it. A good point to handle this step is the startup procedure of the executable. As for reference counting, it depends on how you call `RegisterActiveObject`. If you use the `ACTIVEOBJECT_STRONG` flag, you'll need to explicitly remove the object from the ROT. This is probably the behavior you're looking for. `ACTIVEOBJECT_WEAK` on the other hand releases the object when the last client disconnects from it.

Comment: @Aurora - any chance you know the values of ACTIVEOBJECT_STRONG and ACTIVEOBJECT_WEAK?

Comment: Sure, `ACTIVEOBJECT_STRONG` = 0x0, and `ACTIVEOBJECT_WEAK` = 0x1.